# How to set the default value for a DateTime column in MySQL workbench?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a column CreatedDate and I want to set the below default value in the below format for this column.

**Default value:- yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00.000**

I have tried multiple solutions like I have used DATETIME datatype, TIMESTAMP but it is not taking the default value.

Could someone please share your thoughts on this?

Thanks,

Comment: You're mistaken:  date/times values in databases don't have a "format" - that only applies when their values are displayed on-screen to users.

Comment: Why do you want set the date format? I mean you could format the date in a query or format in the application which used the DB.

Comment: @CodeSun   Actually, i want to set this value as default value  (2017-06-28 hh:mm:ss,000) in the CreatedDate column. I need to set thuis because we have migrated from sql to MySQL and in SQL, the same value was set by default for this column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to set the default value to a specific hard-coded value, you can use the following

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ALTER CreatedDate SET DEFAULT "2017-06-28 00:00:00.000";
```

See [ALTER TABLE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html) docs

Answer (score 2):

The format you show is the default datetime format if you define the column with millisecond precision.

Demo:

```
mysql> create table mytable (id serial primary key, ts datetime(3));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into mytable set ts = now();
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from mytable;
+----+-------------------------+
| id | ts                      |
+----+-------------------------+
|  1 | 2023-03-06 09:15:34.000 |
+----+-------------------------+
```

There is no way to change the default format of a datetime. Datetimes are not stored as a string, they are stored as a binary value. You must use the [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function to display a different format.